# How to call nested conditional void function with onPressed [flutter]

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a customized flutter stepper widget and I want to having conditional back button when I press the backbutton in appbar, it will be back on previous step, just like this

```
    onPressed: () {
    if (currentStep != 0) {
      onStepCancel;
    } else {
      Navigator.pop(context);
      }
    },
```

and somehow onStepCancel is can't be call because it has a value of `final VoidCallback? onStepCancel`, I put another function inside another function A.K.A **nested**, I want to use this widget in another class, so it can be simplify by only putting the void function inside `onStepCancel`

```
      CustomStepper(
      . . .
      currentStep: controller.currentStep.value,
      onStepContinue: controller.increment,    
      onStepCancel: controller.decrement,
     );
```

the void function that fill with decrement function of currentStep will be proceed inside `onStepCancel` and when user click on back button with condition `currentStep != 0` it will show the previous step and when user is reaching `currentStep == 0` it will back to previous page `Navigator.pop(context);`, but the problem is `onStepCancel` can't be `VoidCallback?` because the conditional function is already the void function itself and it can't be returned `VoidCallBack?` inside it, so how can I call `onStepCancel` function inside conditional case with `onPressed`, this is the widget function where I put it:

```
Widget _buttonBack(int stepIndex, BuildContext context) {
    return IconButton(
      onPressed: () {
        if (currentStep != 0) {
          onStepCancel;
        } else {
          Navigator.pop(context);
        }
      },
      icon: SvgPicture.asset(
        Images.backArrowButton,
        color: ColorResources.brandHeavy,
      ),
    );
  }
```

and I want to put `Widget _buttonBack` inside:

```
Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    . . .
    leading: _buttonBack(currentStep, context),
    . . .
);
```

edit:

`onStepCancel` is fullfil with void function that I call from controller:

```
void decrement() => currentStep--;
```

`void decrement()` is the function for getting back to previous `Step` and I call `decrement()` function in onStepCancel just like this:

```
onStepCancel: controller.decrement
```

Inside my `CustomStepper` class, `onStepCancel` will pass `decrement` to `onPressed()`, I have try few way to put conditional onPressed(), with this:

```
onPressed: () => currentStep != 0 ? onStepCancel : Navigator.pop(context),
```

and this

```
onPressed: () {
if (currentStep != 0) {
  onStepCancel;
} else {
  Navigator.pop(context);
  }
},
```

both conditional doesn't work, but the funny thing is when I call `onStepCancel` without conditional case, like this:

```
onPressed: onStepCancel
```

it show no problem and it works well, so the point is, on step cancel will only work well without nested function, I only could call it with `onStepCancel` without any conditional function, how to call nested function? is it needed to be in any other form instead of function or else?

Answer (score 0):

if `onStepCancel` is a callback, you should call it instead of returning it:

```dart
if (currentStep != 0) {
  onStepCancel();
} else {
  Navigator.pop(context);
}
```

Comment: I have try to use onStepCancel with no return before and when I press backbutton on my appbar it doesn't work, it's not back to previous Step

Comment: It sounds like your problem is in the `onStepCancel` function then. You should debug that and figure out why it's not performing the work you want it to. Returning the callback as a value without executing it as in your original code is not going to accomplish anything.

Comment: when I delete conditional function, it works well, `onStepCancel` is work without conditional function, but when I try to add conditional function inside `onPressed` it start to not working, it only works when I call `onStepCancel` directly without using any conditional, that's the problem, how to use conditional if-else in `onPressed` and call `onStepCancel` inside of it